# Can one segment control what tables the other segments point to (Power BI)?

Tags: powerbi

I have a PowerBI dashbaord where I created a segment called Environment with values Production and Staging.

According to selection, the results in my visuals are pointing to tables in Production or Staging environment (in the different measures of my visuals, I have written IF(SELECTEDVALUE(ENVIRONMENT[Value]) = "Production",
[measure that points to production tables],
[measure that points to staging tables])

Only issue is I also have 2 other segments in my dashboard (state, and date range). Those ones are today pointing to Staging environment' tables.
Is there any way to make those segments point to Staging or Production tables according to the selection of the Environment segment ?

Indeed, if I select Production in my Environment segment, the other segments pointing out to Staging tables', they do not filter my visuals' results anymore.. :(  I have tried to create below measure for state segment for example, but does not work.

```
StateFilter = 
IF(
    SELECTEDVALUE(ENVIRONMENT[Value]) = "Production",
    DISTINCT(IN_OUTLET_INFO_PROD[STATE_DESC]),
    DISTINCT(IN_OUTLET_INFO_STG[STATE_DESC])
)
```

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: It sounds like `state` and `date range` do not have a relationship with `environment`.  You might be able to solve this by changing their existing relationships to filter in both directions.  If you provide an image of the model view, that might help.  Also, this approach is a bit unconventional - typically, environments are managed by report parameters which would modify the connection to point to different servers or databases.

Comment: Finally made it work, you were right was a relationship issue with my filters, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it work, here is how if ever can help someone:

- Created a new table StateFilter containing distinct values in STATE_DESC column from both my tables in Staging and in Production:

```
StateFilter = FILTER(DISTINCT(UNION(VALUES(IN_OUTLET_INFO_STG[STATE_DESC]), VALUES(IN_OUTLET_INFO_PROD[STATE_DESC]))), [STATE_DESC] <> BLANK())
```

- Added relationships one to many between StateFilter table and IN_OUTLET_INFO_STG as well as IN_OUTLET_INFO_PROD
- The segment in the visual is now StateFilter and can filter out results whether I have selected Production or Staging (same for my Date Range filter)